# How to call WCF service from ASP.NET without impersonation and explicit credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

Our asp.net site needs to call standalone WCF service (in the same domain).

Application pool runs under `Network Service` account and impersonation is not used.

We also do not want to use credentials for accessing WCF as they require managing them for different environments and deployment configurations.

Is it possible to restrict the access to WCF from this account at particular machine of the domain (web server)?
 
Can we achieve this with web.config settings?